# Hover over Start button to open Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

How can I change some settings or modify windows in registry to open the start menu when I hover over the button? I'm using windows 10 for this to work.

Comment: Use a third-party program that offers this functionality

Comment: This should be feature of W10 without third party programs.

Comment: @Akidus, did you find any solution for this? I am using windows 11 and still don't' have this feature.

Answer (score 2):

Use Autohotkey and get it to track the mouse movement - when it reaches the area of the start button you can simulate a mouse click. Full instructions at http://www.autohotkey.com/

Comment: Would be nice to have a script here that does that.

Comment: Not that simple. You have to see if there already open start window. Otherwise, you will fall in loop of infinite clicks.